# Аномальный вывод десятичного числа в Assembler под DOS

Tags: ассемблер, dos

Ниже дан простейший алгоритм вывода десятичного числа, который почему-то работает совсем неправильно.
Несколько раз прогнал пример на листке - всё правильно.
Фактический результат работы - бесконечно зацикленный вывод последовательности "97531".

```
data segment

data ends

stak segment stack
    db 256 dup (0)
stak ends

code segment
    main proc
        assume ds:data,ss:stak,cs:code

        push data
        pop ds

        mov al,69
        mov bl,10
        L:
            xor ah,ah
            div bl
            mov dl,ah
            add dl,30h
            mov ah,2h
            int 21h
        cmp al,0
        jg L

        mov ax,4c00h
        int 21h
    main endp
code ends

end main
```

Comment: выглядит действительно правильно. Но int 21 может портить любые регистры, какие заблогаруссудится. думаю оно как минимум портит весь ax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я не ошибаюсь, то после вызова функции `02h` прерывания `21h` регистр `AL` содержит последний выведенный символ. То есть данная функция переписывает регистр `AL`.

Вы, например, можете перед вызовом прерывания занести регистр `AX` в стек (с помощью команды `push`), а затем вернуть его из стека (с помощью команды `pop`).